# How to have a URL Icon in a Visual Studio Setup Project?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, icons, shortcut

I have a winforms application which is deployed with a standard windows installer (MSI), created in visual studio. I would like to create a custom shortcut which launches a specific URL.

The shortcut needs to have a custom icon associated with it too.

All I can find is the ability to add a shortcut to an item in the project files (output or manually added files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this - first you create a normal URL shortcut in your solution folder with the icon in the same folder, you then add those as normal files to the installer and lastly you use the installer interface to create a shortcut.

In essence the shortcut points to the shortcut which knows the location of the icon file since it is relative to the second shortcut.